# Refresh array in TableView Custom Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I have a ViewController that has a TableView generated with Custom Cells. Each Custom Cell has a NSDictionary that generates few arrays.

I want to find the way to replace one array in Custom Cell using `[myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:... withObject:...]` **pointing towards a specific cell in a TableView**, provided that **I already know the indexPath** of that cell that contains that array.

Another words I have to somehow indicate that Custom Cell indexPath, get there and refresh array.

Is there a way to accomplish that mission in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a cell reference using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` call if you know the indexPath of the cell that you want to change if each of your custom cell is different unique.

But I strongly recommend changing the data model by getting it using cell location as the reference. Because table views reuse cell you could end up with unexpected results. You should instead change your table model and then reload the table or perhaps reload just the specific cells that have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the indexPath of your cell, you can do something like:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPathOfYourCell, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: The problem is that every Custom Cell has a collectionView with set of images that after the second refresh are loosing the order and jumping from one cell to another. That's why I was trying to exactly target the array location and change it.

Answer (score 0):

You got several option for reloading the `UITableView` taken inside the `UIViewController`

say your table view is such

```
    UITableView *tableView
```

case 1: **Reload the whole table view** [appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData)

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

case 2: **Reload all the rows inside a section** [appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:yourIndexPath withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

case 3: **Reload multiple section at once** [appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadSections:withRowAnimation:)

```
tableView reloadSections:yourIndexPathSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

NB :: must do any of these operation in your **mainThread** / **gui thread**.

Comment: Problem is that `[tableview reloadData]` doesn't refresh arrays that are generated in Custom Cells. I have no idea why. The other two do the trick, however the problem is that every Custom Cell has a collectionView with set of images that after the second refresh are loosing the order and jumping from one cell to another.

Comment: you have to manually update the arrays (data), `[tableView reloadData]` is not meant to reload the data portion, its just reload the `tableView` (cells) according to your data you provided. After the new data is populated, then just call the `[tableView reloadData]`. Keep mind to call it from the **mainThread**. Hope i got your point.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm trying to figure out is how to target that specific array, located in a specific Custom Cell (and I know indexPath), update it and then call for `[tableview reloadData]`.

Comment: i am doing case 2 in view will appear as i want to refresh single table view cell but row data is not changing...how to call method from main thread?

Comment: `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
//  your code goes here
}];`

Answer (score 0):

Solution.

First, we need to make sure that every Custom Cell has a `@property NSInteger cellIndex;`. When tableView populates Custom Cells, make sure to add `cell.cellIndex = indexPath.row;`. That way every Custom Cell will have it equal to tableView row.

Second, when making changes in parent viewController, in the end of update we post notification `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshCollectionView" object:self];`.

Third, in Custom Cell we listen to that notification: 
    `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshCollect) name:@"refreshCollectionView" object:nil];`. That triggers method (also included in Custom Cell) with reference to cellIndex:

```
-(void) refreshCollect {

    if (cellIndex == [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"cellIndex"] intValue]) {

       NSURL *newsImgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/core/functions/ios/page.news.image?news_id=%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"newsID"]]];
       NSData *newsImgData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:newsImgURL] returningResponse:nil error:nil];

       newsImgDict    = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:newsImgData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
       newsImgID2     = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [newsImgDict valueForKey:@"image_id"]];
       newsImgTime    = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [newsImgDict valueForKey:@"timestamp"]];
       newsIDImg      = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [newsImgDict valueForKey:@"news_id"]];
       newsImgDescr   = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [newsImgDict valueForKey:@"description"]];
       newsImgExt2    = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [newsImgDict valueForKey:@"ext"]];

} }
```

In my case I have NSDictionary that rebuilds some arrays just for that particular Custom Cell.